# Custom navigation route

Tags: skmaps

Is there any possibility to create a custom navigation route with a *free* route mode type? I would like to create a route in a park or on a river (without any reasons) that could navigate user on it.

While creating a custom track and applying it in the DemoApp it displays my map properly but it applies/calculates it all the time as a road ... so I'm seeing my track/road and the calculated road beside. I assume it's due to having wrong SKRouteMode but I don't see any custom one.

Thanks.

Bart S.

Answer (score 2):

With the car routing profile you can only drive on roads - if you use this profile it will always use the nearest road point available (if one such point is available).

For the bike/pedestrian routing profiles, they are capable of using non-road points but the default routing algorithm does not have enough data to create a route in that park. I.e. if you give it just one point in the park (the destination) it will assume that you've made an error (or that the point has low GPS accuracy).

What you want to do is give it "a lot of points" in that park - you need to teach it that there is a road in that park which it is not aware of and he should trust you and route there. See this [blog article](http://sdkblog.skobbler.com/creating-routes-from-gps-points-gpx-track-navigation/) detailing this.

The above statement implies that at least you know the way to that park (know the existence of that road and can provide that information to the routing engine) - if you don't know this information then no route can be created to that park.

Comment: Thanks Ando for quick response. Actually I've found the blog site like 3 hours after I've posted my question.

So yes, I know exactly where I want the road to be, where the road actually is. I hope that this *a lot of points* case will also adapt to rivers in cities (not only parks, the algorithm must trust me) ... anyway I will test it a get back to you. Thanks